# How to get the full file path of the browsed file in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a browse control in Django application, which is reading only the file of the browsed file.What I required is full file path of the browsed file.

I have tried the different attributes for the browse control and its not working.

To read the text of file control:

```
request.POST["BrowseControlName"]
```

It was returning the only file name not the absolute file path

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. Are you looking for `request.path`?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't access the full path; the browser doesn't send it for security reasons.

Comment: Is there any other workaround to achieve this or any other alternative to do so?

Comment: Not that I know of. What do you need the path for anyway?

Comment: I thought of copying the files in my application folder and and the processing them as I wished? Is it works?